# Getting SVG to work on Android 2.*

Tags: wordpress, svg

I am creating a website and it's using SVG images due to retina support. I had to use modernizer to swap SVG for .PNG and also use alternative .PNGs for IE8.

I now have the problem the images are not showing on my Samsung Galaxy Ace with Android version 2.3.6.

How can I get the phone to support SVG images?

Thank you kind people.

Answer (score 1):

The stock android browser didn't start supporting svg until Android version 3.0, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg.

You can find alternative free browsers that do support SVG on android 2.3, such as Opera Mobile (disclaimer: I work at Opera).

The modernizr solution should work just fine ([see guide](http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/)), though you will get PNGs in the stock browser on Android 2.3.